# Visual Composer broken on production serve but works fine on local

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, wordpress-theming, visual-composer

I have a site which is on WordPress, Every time i import a local DB to the production server , First of all the PhpMyAdmin does not allow to import the  entire Database in one go. it gives an error stating `"Duplicate entry for primary key for wp_options` table, I manually comment out the  wp_options table and import it separately. Now when i login to the production serve in WordPress i am not able to see the VC editor.